# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when Invoking generic reflective method

Tags: c#, exception, generics, reflection, azure-mobile-services

So this problem is quite confusing. And its fairly complicated and abstract so I'm going to try my best to explain it.

I have 3 classes `LinkedIn`, `Facebook`, and `Twitter`. All of them inherit from a common base class `SocialBase` which only has one property: `uuid` and this property is only used so we can find the actual types in the database.

So I have this one function that accepts a `Profile` class which contains foreign keys to all `LinkedIn`, `Facebook`, and `Twitter` tables, as well as an Enum value that will tell us whether to look for the `LinkedIn`, the `Facebook`, or the `Twitter` foreign keys

```
public static async Task UnlinkSocialAccountFromProfile(Profile prof, SocialNetworks provider)
    {
        //TYPE variable of LinkedIn, Facebook, or Twitter
        var handler = HandlerMapping[provider];
        //client is MobileServiceClient
        var method = client.GetType().GetMethod("GetTable", Type.EmptyTypes);
        //MobileServiceClient.GetTable<handler>()
        var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(handler);
        //IMobileServiceTable<handler> 
        var table = generic.Invoke(client, null);
        //Profile has 3 foreign keys, LinkedinUUID, FacebookUUID, TwitterUUID, we want the <handler>UUID
        string propertyValue = prof.GetType().GetProperty(handler.Name + "UUID").GetValue(prof) as string;
        //Invoke Extension method with our generic types
        var genMethod =
            typeof (Extensions).GetMethod("FilterByNamedProperty")
                .MakeGenericMethod(table.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0], propertyValue.GetType());
        //Get the List<handler> that results from our query
        var result = await (Task<List<Linkedin>>)(genMethod.Invoke(null, new [] {table, "uuid", propertyValue}));
        //var result = await (table as IMobileServiceTable<SocialBase>).FilterByNamedProperty("uuid", propertyValue);
        await new SocialResources().DeleteIfExists((result as IList<SocialBase>)[0]);
}
```

So what I'm doing here is getting the `Type` of the class, so this will be one of the `SocialBase` subclasses. For this particular example I know I'm going to be looking for the `LinkedIn` type. So after getting type `LinkedIn` I need to invoke the generic method from my `MobileServiceTable` so normally it would look like `MobileServiceTable.GetTable<LinkedIn>()` but thanks to reflection we have to take the longer route around this.

After getting my returned instance of `IMobileServiceTable<LinkedIn>` I get value of the foreign key I'm looking for. In this case it will be called `LinkedInUUID`. Now here comes the tricky part. I have this extension method that will construct my query expression for me since it has to be of type `Expression<Func<LinkedIn, bool>>`

```
public async static Task<List<TSource>> FilterByNamedProperty<TSource, TValue>(this IMobileServiceTable<TSource> source, string propertyName, TValue value)
    {
        // uuid
        var property = typeof(TSource).GetProperty(propertyName);
        // (TSource)p
        var parExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource));
        //p.uuid
        var methodExp = Expression.Property(parExp, property);
        // value
        var constExp = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue));
        // p.uuid == value
        var binExp = Expression.Equal(methodExp, constExp);
        // p => p.uuid == value
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(binExp, parExp);
        return await source.Where(lambda).ToListAsync(); 
    }
```

I believe the comments do a pretty good job of explaining the build process as each statement occurs. However, once we get to the `return await ...` the application will crash. Here is the output right before that line and the error immediately following.

`IMobileServiceTable<TSource> source = {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable<SocialConnect.Linkedin>}` (Correct)

`propertyName = uuid` (Correct)

`TValue value = dscRJQSIxJaEfd` (Correct)

I have a strong feeling the problem is with my `lambda` expression, but if I test the extension with this line `var test = await (source as IMobileServiceTable<Linkedin>).Where(p => p.uuid == (value as string)).ToListAsync();` it works perfectly fine. But as soon as I change it to use the `lambda` variable than I get the exception. The actual value of the lambda expression is `{Param_0 => (Param_0.uuid == "dscRJQSIxJaEfd")}` which looks correct

Any ideas?

**EDIT**
Sorry, here is the actual exception from stack trace

```
`A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Query.FilterBuildingExpressionVisitor.GetTableMemberName(Expression expression, MobileServiceContractResolver contractResolver)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Query.FilterBuildingExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberAccess(MemberExpression expression)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Query.FilterBuildingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Query.FilterBuildingExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression expression)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Query.FilterBuildingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Query.FilterBuildingExpressionVisitor.Compile(Expression expression, MobileServiceContractResolver contractResolver)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Query.MobileServiceTableQueryTranslator1.AddFilter(MethodCallExpression expression)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Query.MobileServiceTableQueryTranslator1.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression expression)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Query.MobileServiceTableQueryTranslator1.Visit(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Query.MobileServiceTableQueryTranslator1.Translate()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Query.MobileServiceTableQueryProvider.Compile[T](IMobileServiceTableQuery1 query)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Query.MobileServiceTableQueryProvider.<Execute>d__31.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Query.MobileServiceTableQuery1.<ToListAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult()
   at SocialConnect.Models.Extensions.<FilterByNamedProperty>d__22.MoveNext() in MobileServiceSample\MobileServiceSample\Extensions.cs:line 55`
```

Comment: An AggregateException just holds other exceptions.  What does YOURS hold?

Comment: Can you post the content of file MobileServiceSample\MobileServiceSample\Extensions.cs?

Comment: The `FilterByNamedProperty` is the only method in that class that should be of concern. Plus its a static class used for extension methods, so as you can see in my previous example I'm able to call it without an instance of any class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I finally solved this issue. Apparently the problem wasn't with the query or anything I was doing, but with the `SocialBase` class. I had been using it to make methods where I knew the generic type `TEntity` would have a `uuid` property so I could easily find it in any database. But I guess the field was not getting serialized properly and that was what was causing the `NullReferenceException`. After removing the base class and just reflectively finding the property and value then everything starting working fine.

I don't understand why it wasn't working properly before because I had been using the base `SocialBase` class for a lot of situations before this.